# Electron: How do implement "open with" / have the "open-file" app event on MacOS called?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, open-with

According to the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos) the following should do it:

```
app.on("open-file", (event, path) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("OPEN FILE???");
});
```

The console log is never called. I have tried:

- Choosing "open with" and the application by right clicking on a file.
- Use open with while the app is open.
- Dragging a file on the dock icon.

It might be quite significant how I build it too. I use `electron-builder` and have this in my package.json:

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myname.someid",
    "mac": {
      "fileAssociations": [
        {
          "ext": [
            "mp3"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Then I run `electron-builder` after installing it.

I have retested it in electron-quick-start and after following the above steps it still fails.

According to this tutorial this is also how you should do it:

https://roysegall.medium.com/electron-open-with-for-mac-osx-f215a1fe2ce1